# How can I find the length of a particular string in array of pointer to string?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, string-length

How can I find the length of a string from an array of pointers to a string?

For example, if I want to find the length of the string "apple" then how can I calculate length of it? I tried many ways, but I couldn’t. If I do sizeof(str[0]), it returns the size of the pointer (4 bytes in my 32-bit device). Are they stored in the memory location next to each other or not?

```
const char *str[] = {
    "apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "mep", "helsdf"
};
```

Comment: They might be next to each other, and they might not be. They could be in any order, with any number of bytes between strings. When writing C, the code should be designed so that you don't need to know and don't care where string literals are stored.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking to different and unrelated questions. The length of each string is well defined, but it won't tell you anything about whether they're adjacent in memory. Also, *why* do you want to know whether they're adjacent in memory? (Idle curiosity is a perfectly valid reason; I can't think of another one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use strlen() from string.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char *str[] = {
        "apple", "ball", "cat", "dog", "mep", "helsdf"
    };

    printf("Length of \"%s\": %zu\n", str[0], strlen(str[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... and i want to know if they are stored in memory location next to each other or not?

To check that you need to look at pointer values and to do some pointer arithmetic.

Like:

```
// Print the location of each substring
for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof str / sizeof str[0]); ++i)
{
        printf("%p : %s\n", (void*)str[i], str[i]);
}

// Check if str[i+1] is located just after str[i]
for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof str / sizeof str[0] - 1); ++i)
{
    if ( (str[i] + strlen(str[i]) + 1) == str[i+1] )
    {
        printf("%s is stored just after %s\n", str[i+1], str[i]);
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
0x558cfd6e5004 : apple
0x558cfd6e500a : ball
0x558cfd6e500f : cat
0x558cfd6e5013 : dog
0x558cfd6e5017 : mep
0x558cfd6e501b : helsdf
ball is stored just after apple
cat is stored just after ball
dog is stored just after cat
mep is stored just after dog
helsdf is stored just after mep
```

Remember that the result of the above code may change every time you compile your source code.